# Can perks be "prestiged" multiple times?

Tags: killing-floor-2

I am currently participating in the beta of Killing Floor 2.

Today I noticed the following:

[image]

Does that number mean that perks can be prestiged multiple times?

If yes, what happens when they get prestiged again? More Vault dosh? different weapon skins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the [2019-06-18 "Back & Kickin’ Brass" update](https://steamcommunity.com/games/232090/announcements/detail/2431295861160169322), perks can be prestiged up to rank **5**.

---

When you Prestige a Perk, you reset it back to Level 0, losing access to all of its Perk Bonuses and Perk Skills until you level it back up. In exchange you are given a special Weapon Skin, along with a modified Perk Icon and 2,000,000 Vosh (enough for 4 Vault Crates). You are also given an Experience boost so leveling up the next time will go by faster.

There are (currently) no Achievements tied to Prestiging, and the rewards are purely cosmetic so the feature can be ignored if you so choose.

**Rank 1 Prestige Rewards**

- Experience Bonus: 30%
- Weapon Skin: Knives for each Perk

**Rank 2 Prestige Rewards**

- Experience Bonus: 35%
- Weapon Skin: Tier 1 Weapons for each Perk

**Rank 3 Prestige Rewards**

- Experience Bonus: 40%
- Weapon Skin: Tier 2 Weapons for each Perk

**Rank 4 Prestige Rewards**

- Experience Bonus: 45%
- Weapon Skin: Tier 3 Weapons for each Perk

<sup>Source: https://killingfloor.fandom.com/wiki/Prestige</sup>

---

Attempting to prestige past the maximum level will present you with the error message, "[Max perk prestige level achieved!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRg38.jpg)"

Answer (score 4):

I have searched a bit the official forums and I came across [this post](https://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/forum/killing-floor-2/killing-floor-2-general/general-discussion-af/2320150-perk-icons#post2320150)

> Hey Tripwire,
>   I see the perk screen counts my prestige level. This implies that eventually we will be able to reset our levels more than once. Will the perk icons keep changing and getting upgraded more? At what prestige level will we earn the final, most fancy perk icon?

The only useful answer so far says that

> New icons already in
>   [image]
>
> At least that's how they look now

---

On the 6th Sept 2018, with the beta preview of [build 1069](https://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/forum/killing-floor-2/kf2-news-and-announcements/news-and-announcements-af/2324081-monster-masquerade-opt-in-beta-is-now-live-build-1069-for-clients-and-servers), the second tier of prestige has been unlocked:

> - Prestige System
>
>   - Prestige Rank 2 is now available

and this is what the interface provides:

[image]

- 35% xp bonus (tier 1 provides 30%)
- 2000000 vosh (in addition to the 2000000 of tier 1)
- a skin for the tier 1 weapon of the class (in addition to the knife skin of tier 1)

---

Since [4th Dec 2018](https://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/forum/killing-floor-2/kf2-news-and-announcements/news-and-announcements-af/2327376-killing-floor-2-twisted-christmas-2018-is-here), the third tier is unlocked:

> - Prestige System
>
>   - Prestige Rank 3 is now available

and it provides:

- 40% xp bonus
- 2000000 vosh
- a skin for a tier 2 weapon of the interested class